# Start audio recording when the application is in background on jailbreak iOS device

Tags: ios, audio-recording

Is there a way to **start the audio** recording when the **application is in background**. It doesn't looks possible if we intend to hit app store. But since we are developing on Jailbreak device I wouldn't mind using any private frameworks or hacks.

Also anybody worked out how to prevent the red status bar while record is happening in the background.

Comment: I was able to achieve this by running a daemon process and then triggering the recording through it. I used AudioQueue to do the recording.